# Can I use both spatial index and partition together

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, spatial-index

I have a table that has structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyGeoLocationInfo](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Geocode] [geography] NOT NULL,
    [GeocodeText] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [StateGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyGeoLocationInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to know if there is a way of define spatial index on `Geocode` column and create partition on `StateGroupId` column

Initially, my table has only one primary culstered index on `Id`.Firstly, I first tried to create partition on `StateGroupId` column. The script was:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [StateGroupPF](int) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'1', N'2', N'3', N'4', N'5', N'6', N'7', N'8', N'9', N'10', N'11', N'12', N'13', N'14', N'15', N'16', N'17', N'18', N'19', N'20', N'21', N'22', N'23', N'24', N'25', N'26', N'27', N'28', N'29', N'30', N'31', N'32', N'33', N'34', N'35', N'36', N'37', N'38', N'39', N'40', N'41', N'42', N'43', N'44', N'45', N'46', N'47', N'48', N'49', N'50', N'51', N'52', N'53', N'54', N'55', N'56', N'57', N'58')


CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [StateGroupPS] AS PARTITION [StateGroupPF] TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY])


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CompanyGeoLocationInfo] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyGeoLocationInfo]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CompanyGeoLocationInfo] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyGeoLocationInfo] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_StateGroupPS_635860762633977740] ON [dbo].[CompanyGeoLocationInfo]
(
    [StateGroupId]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [StateGroupPS]([StateGroupId])


DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_StateGroupPS_635860762633977740] ON [dbo].[CompanyGeoLocationInfo]


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Then, I tried to define spatial index. The error was something like "For spatial index, the table should have primary clustered index".

Secondly, I first defined spatial index on Geocode column, than I tried to create partition. This time I got "Could not drop the primary key constraint 'PK_CompanyGeoLocationInfo' because the table has an XML or spatial index."
error.

Is there any direct or workaround solution for that?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried and been unsuccessful?

Comment: spatial index requires primary clustered index, but for partitioning it should be nonclustered. Yes I tried it, I couldnt achieve it, an error occured

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the entire structure of your table (i.e. what indexes you currently have on it, partitioning information, etc), what you've tried so far, and what error you're getting?

Comment: I edited question, and tried to explain details.

Comment: You've got problems before you even start. Specifically, spatial indexes require a clustered primary key, which you don't have. I'm guessing that StateGroupId won't be unique so that's not a PK candidate.

Comment: yes StateGroupId is not unique. I only has 50 values over 20M row data. Is there any workaround solution? for example, can you suggest that spliting table  into 2 tables by columns. One has partition,other has spatial index. While querying, I can inner join them

Comment: Maybe. Are your geography items unique? If so, splitting the table probably isn't going to work all that well as the cardinality of the spatial table and non-spatial table will be the equal. That would allow you to partition the non-spatial data almost trivially, though (you'd need to put the StateGroupID column into the clustered index, but that's not a big deal). If, however, it's on the other extreme like one geography item per StateGroupID, then make the table of the 50 (StateGroupID, GeoCode, GeoCodeText) tuples and pull the latter two columns out of your table.

Comment: geography items are not unique, There are 11 M unique item in 20 M. One geography item may have more than one StateGroupID. I think I will try to exclude [StateGroupId] to another table that has columns "CompanyGeoLocationInfoId" and [StateGroupId]  and define partition on it.

Comment: Hmm… I just want to make sure that you're partitioning for the right reasons. Partitioning is more of a data management strategy than a performance one. That is, it allows you to move large amounts of data into and out of a table with what amounts to a metadata change. Give the numbers you're talking about (≈ 20m rows), it doesn't sound like you have the amount of data that I'd typically see in a partitioning scheme. Unless it's particularly volatile. So, just make sure that whatever benefit you're getting from partitioning is worth the overhead.

Comment: My aiming goal is that doing geographic search over 20 M data is very slow. I splitted the rows into 50 separated region. So the main purpose is performance. Do you thing only index solve it? By the way thanks for your comments

Comment: If you don't already have a spatial index over your data, do that. Also, I created a chat room if you'd like to discuss further: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/33423/can-i-use-both-spatial-index-and-partition-together?tab=general